# how to find two values between a range in mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to list id's where it only has 12 - 18 reviews.

In the database it shows as

```
**"example" : [
5,
10
],**
```

The 5, 10 is the number of reviews
so 5 meaning 5 reviews out of 10 views.

I have tried the below however doesn't work.

```
db.student.find({ u1 : { $gt :  5, $lt : 10}});
```

any help guys?

Comment: Take a look at this document about the Dot Notation https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation

Comment: @rodrigoap I have tried dot notation, however this doesn't work. 
I only want number where in my example is 10 to be a max of 18 or a lowest to 12

Comment: Can you edit your question to show what you're trying with dot notation?

Comment: Try using $and operator.https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/

Comment: can you elaborate, JSON document and expected output

Answer (score 1):

This query will give you the documents with: review count: 4 to 7 **AND** view count: 10 to 20.

```
db.getCollection("student").find({
    "example.0":{$gt:4, $lt:7}, 
    "example.1":{$gt:10, $lt:20}
})
```

I think you can modify the query above to suit your needs since your question is not totally clear to me.